# Using Scilab, Get transfer function closed loop

Tags: scilab, pid-controller, xcos

I have a XCOS scheme, where are presents:

- My system G(Z)
- A Pid controller

[image: Xcos scheme]

Now, I would like to know the closed loop transfer function.

How can i obtain it by scilab/Xcos ?

Thanks

Best

*** EDIT: ****

Following user1149326's suggestions :

```
loadXcosLibs(); loadScicos();
importXcosDiagram("/home/dursino/Desktop/nostro_sistema.xcos");
for i=1:length(scs_m.objs)
if typeof(scs_m.objs(i))=="Block" & scs_m.objs(i).gui=="SUPER_f" then
    scs_m = scs_m.objs(i).model.rpar;
    break;
end
```

end

```
-->sys = lincos(scs_m);
```

The last statement return this:
lincos: Unable to find diagram inputs
at line     118 of function lincos called by :
sys = lincos(scs_m);

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lincos](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/lincos.html) to create a linear state-space model from a general dynamical system described by a xcos diagram.

After obtaining the state-space model you can use [ss2tf](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.0/fr_FR/ss2tf.html) to convert it to a transfer function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was usefull..
I have a problem:

lincos: Error during block parameters evaluation.

Now I'm searching a solution.. If you have it please write!
Best
at line      85 of function lincos called by :  
sys = lincos(scs_m);

Comment: I don't quite follow your comment @Edge7, could provide your code and the complete error message?

Comment: You can edit you original question and add a update with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @spoorcc, you can use *[lincos](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/lincos.html)* to get the state-space representation of the system you made in Xcos. One important thing to remember is that you should use [IN_f](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/IN_f.html) as the input and [OUT_f](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/OUT_f.html) as the output in Xcos. Only then you can get the state-space representation using *lincos*. I think you didn't use these in your Xcos model and that's why you got that error.

P.S. I know this answer probably won't help the OP (it's been 8 years now since it was asked) but I hope this might help someone like me who spent a lot on time searching for this method.